# Find way to separate array so each subarrays sum is less or equal to a number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, complexity-theory

I have a mathematical/algorithmic problem here.

Given an array of numbers, find a way to separate it to 5 subarrays, so that sum of each subarrays is less than or equal to a given number. All numbers from the initial array, must go to one of the subarrays, and be part of one sum.

So the input to the algorithm would be:
d - representing the number that each subarrays sum has to be less or equal
A - representing the array of numbers that will be separated to different subarrays, and will be part of one sum

Algorithm complexity must be polynomial.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: can you have negative values? can you modify the order of the input?

Answer (score 1):

If by "subarray" you mean "subset" as opposed to "contiguous slice", it is impossible to find a polynomial time algorithm for this problem (unless P = NP). The [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) is to partition a list of numbers into to sets such that the sum of both sets are equal. It is known to be NP-complete. The partition problem can be reduced to your problem as follows:

Suppose that `x1, ..., x_n` are positive numbers that you want to partition into 2 sets such that their sums are equal. Let `d` be this common sum (which would be the sum of the `xi` divided by 2). extend `x_i` to an array, `A`, of size `n+3` by adding three copies of `d`. Clearly the only way to partition `A` into 5 subarrays so that the sum of each is less than or equal to `d` is if the sum of each actually equals `d`. This would in turn require 3 of the subarrays to have length 1, each consisting of the number `d`. The remaining 2 subarrays would be exactly a partition of the original `n` numbers.

On the other hand, if there are additional constraints on what the numbers are and/or the subarrays need to be, there might be a polynomial solution. But, if so, you should clearly spell out what there constraints are.

Answer (score 0):

Set up of the problem:
d : the upper bound for the subarray
A : the initial array

Assuming A is not sorted.
(Heuristic)
Algorithm:

1.Sort A in ascending order using standard sorting algorithm->O(nlogn)

2.Check if the largest element of A is greater than d ->(constant)
  if yes, no solution
  if no, continue
3.Sum up all the element in A, denote S. Check if S/5 > d ->O(n)
  if yes, no solution
  if no, continue

4.Using greedy approach, create a new subarray Asi, add next biggest element aj in the sorted A to Asi so that the sum of Asi does not exceed d. Remove aj from sorted A  ->O(n)

5. repeat step4 until either of the condition satisfied:

   I.At creating subarray Asi, there are only 5-i element left
    In this case, split the remaining element to individual subarray, done

   II. i = 5. There are 5 subarray created.

The algorithm described above is bounded by O(nlogn) therefore in polynomial time.

Comment: But this heuristic isn't guaranteed to find a solution, even when a solution exists.

Comment: Why this is a heuristic?

Comment: Unless you have just solved P=NP (in an unexpected way) your solution can be no more than heuristic. You are doing something which is akin to a best-fit bin-packing algorithm. Things along that line don't  always work.

Comment: But for some `d` the only feasible solutions are with equality. Your solution needs to work for all `d` for which there is a feasible solution, and not just for `d` that have a lot of slack.

Comment: Initially, I think this is a NP problem as well. To be particular, I thought it was asking to solve the subset sum problem. When I read more carefully. The constraint of this problem is less strict than the subset sum. Subset sum require strict equality. However, this problem only require "sum of each subarrays is less than or equal to a given number". Therefore, I think can be solved in poly.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to consider the boundary case that 5*d = Sum(A). In this case, it is indeed a NP problem. Thanks.